# Excel: Capitalize first character of each word

Tags: excel, text, excel-formula, capitalize

I the following text:

```
Your number's up (season 2)
```

I want to change it to:

```
Your Number's Up
```

However, I get this right now with the following code:

```
Your Number'S Up

=TRIM(PROPER(IFERROR(LEFT(A6976,FIND("(",A6976)-1),A6976)))
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With data in **A1**, use:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(PROPER(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"'","zzz")),"zzz","'")
```

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

Do drop the parenthetical part, use:

```
=MID(SUBSTITUTE(PROPER(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"'","zzz")),"zzz","'"),1,FIND("(",SUBSTITUTE(PROPER(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"'","zzz")),"zzz","'"))-1)
```

**EDIT#2:**

See if this is any better:

```
=MID(SUBSTITUTE(PROPER(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"'","zzz")),"zzz","'"),1,FIND("(",SUBSTITUTE(PROPER(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"'","zzz")),"zzz","'") & "(")-1)
```

*(the trick is to insure the `FIND()` function cannot fail.)*

Comment: This works but could you include the bit of code that keeps everything to the left of "(". I updated the original post - sorry!

Comment: @Boosted_d16  see my **EDIT#1:**

Comment: @B  see my **EDIT#2**

Comment: Thanks a lot for the effort :)